# ObjectListView - Objects updating and columns disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

This is kind of a 2-in-1 question, actually. I'm writing a quick software where I have a plain old ObjectListView. Nothing fancy. It displays a List<CharacterWho> where CharacterWho is:

```
public class CharacterWho
{
    [OLVColumn(Width = 150, DisplayIndex = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn(Width = 150, DisplayIndex = 1)]
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn(Width = 75, DisplayIndex = 3)]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn(Width = 75, DisplayIndex = 2)]
    public string Race { get; set; }

}
```

Columns are generated in the form's InitializeComponent:

```
Generator.GenerateColumns(_whoListView, typeof(CharacterWho), true);
```

Every five seconds, my apps polls the server and retrieves a new List to display. So I do this:

```
_whoListView.UpdateObjects(StaticWorld.WhoData);
```

During execution, the columns disappear. I am forced to re-use the generator. If I use ClearObjects(), it removes the columns too:

```
_whoListView.ClearObjects(); // Removes columns
Generator.GenerateColumns(_whoListView, typeof(CharacterWho), true);
_whoListView.SetObjects(StaticWorld.WhoData);
```

That "solution" creates something rather unaesthetic, as the control flickers during the updates...

Is this intended behavior ? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the columns "disappear", or is their width just becoming too small ?

Comment: They totally disappear off the screen, Windows renders a listview without column headers. I did not check the internals (using OLV as a NuGet package)

Comment: Well, that's why I'm asking if you can validate whether or not the columns are still present within the OLV data structure because your not seeing it on screen could be just an artifact caused by 0 width columns.

Comment: You could check programatically if the columns are still there. And are you sure you want to `UpdateObjects()`? The objects you query from the server are probably not related to the references to the objects in the OLV. So you may want to call `SetObjects()`. Maybe this is related to your problem.

Comment: You should definitely be using SetObjects() rather than UpdateObjects().

Comment: Looking at the code in ObjectListView, there is nothing in UpdateObjects() that would change the columns. I would guess you have a call to Clear() somewhere in your code. Clear() is a standard ListView method which removes all rows AND all columns.